# PayPal Android SDK not working with other currency than USD

Tags: android, paypal, currency, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented PayPal Android SDK for purchasing in my App. The cost I am getting is in Australian Dollar, while I was testing I used "USD" in instancing PayPal object. But when I change it to "AUD", I get back `PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID` in my onActivityResult.

This is my instantiation call

```
thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(fees), "AUD",  courseTitle);
```

The sandbox account I am using for testing is Australian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These FAQs may help you:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions

Currently, only USD is supported.

Answer (score 0):

As of release 1.1, other currencies are supported. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/1.1.0